# How to rewrite if exists a php file with the same name?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was searching in Google this question very much time but I don't find any answer.

I want to rewrite http_//mydomain.com/**f** to http_//mydomain.com/

This is my .htaccess code:

```
Rewriterule ^f$ / [R=301,L]
```

rewrite works, **but if exists a file called f.php, then doesn't work**

I tried to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^f$ / [R=301,L]
```

also I tried to do this:

```
Rewriterule ^f([^\.php])$ / [R=301,L]
```

But doesn't work. 
I need help  Is possible this rewrite?? or I should delete f.php file?
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: your first rule should work without a problem because you arent bothering to detect for the presence of that file. Do you have any other rules in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the solution
I have to disable MultiViews directive

```
Options -MultiViews
```

then, rewrite works with file name "f.php" existing

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect any /f/(*) to /

```
 RewriteRule /f/(.*) /$1 [R,NE]
```